# Is there a faster way to build my Docker SQL Server image and import my .dacpac file?

Tags: sql-server, docker, dockerfile, docker-container, dacpac

I want to create a Docker image for a SQL Server.  My database structure is stored in a file (`db.dacpac`).  I have the below ...

```
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest
  
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install unzip -y

RUN wget -progress=bar:force -q -O sqlpackage.zip https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=873926 \
    && unzip -qq sqlpackage.zip -d /opt/sqlpackage \
    && chmod +x /opt/sqlpackage/sqlpackage

...
CMD /bin/bash ./entrypoint.sh
```

In my shell file I have

```
...
/opt/sqlpackage/sqlpackage /a:Publish /tsn:. /tdn:${DB_NAME} /tu:sa /tp:$DB_PASS /sf:/sqlscripts/bin/Debug/db.dacpac
...
```

As I spin up my Docker container, I find that spinning it up is taking some time (I'm using the image for testing) and I would like to speed up building the container.  Is there a more efficient way to import the `.dacpac` file or is there another SQL Server Docker image I should be using to make the process of building the container and importing my database structure faster?

Comment: If this is a one-time db instance for running tests then you probably can generate deployscript during docker image build process and include it (ready to run deploy script) into this image. Running a script is faster then running `sqlpackage publush` which involves model analysis and comparison with target database structure.